# Debugging Haskell

Tags: debugging, haskell, functional-programming

I'm new to functional programming and I'd like to debug a recursive function to see why I am getting particular value as return value. How do I accomplish that? I found some answers on this site as well as on online, but I can't get my head wrap around the idea of doing that. Any help would be appreciated.

```
recur = \a -> if a>100 then  a-10 else recur (recur (a+11))
```

Comment: You really can't debug in Haskell in the traditional sense, because Haskell, being a purely functional language, does not change state during execution. That said, I usually trace through recursive algorithms on paper.

Comment: I tried tracing it on paper but it results in infinite loop. But when I run the function in haskell, it returns result. So, there's gotta be a point where Haskell stops evaluating the argument that I'm passing and I don't know which.

Comment: @Tetramputechture Not really. There is [`Debug.Trace`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Debug-Trace.html), and also there are the debugging commands in GHCi. That said, tracing algorithms on paper is a very good suggestion indeed.

Comment: I also suggest using [trace](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Debug-Trace.html#v:trace)

Comment: @duplode thanks for the info! didn't know about that module.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do this (using [`Debug.Trace`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Debug-Trace.html)):

```
import Debug.Trace (trace)

recur a | trace ("recur " ++ show a) False = undefined
recur a = if a>100 then  a-10 else recur (recur (a+11))
```

This produces output each time the function `recur` is called (or rather, because Haskell is lazy, each time the result of applying `recur` is needed).

Sample output (in ghci):

```
*Main> recur 99
recur 99
recur 110
recur 100
recur 111
recur 101
91
```